# Why do the non-Japanese characters sometimes refer to Buranki as "déraciné"?

Tags: bubuki-buranki

While the Japanese characters in the show typically refer to the giants as "Buranki", some non-Japanese characters (particularly Guy) sometimes refer to them as "déraciné".

This is a curious name for them - the French word "déraciné" means "one who has been displaced". In a sense, this is an appropriate name for the ones that have fallen from Treasure Island, which was their "home". But not all Buranki on Earth are ones that have fallen from Treasure Island; indeed, the majority were probably on Earth to begin with.

In a different sense, this name is also an appropriate way of describing all Buranki, given that

> the Buranki are genuine alien lifeforms who left their home in search of a new one and ended up on Earth.

However, this fact is not widely known; only the people most involved with Buranki are aware of this.

This being the case, why are they called déraciné?